# How to use a custom Rank to GPU mapping in Pytorch Distributed

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm running PyTorch distributed on a single 4-gpu node, where I am not the only one running projects. As a result, sometimes certain GPUs are too busy, while others are idle.

Let's say GPU 0 and GPU 2 are busy, but GPU 1 and GPU 3 are not, so I want to use just these GPUs. It seems that by default, Rank 0 is always GPU 0 in pytorch distributed.

How can I specify to PyTorch that Rank 0 should correspond to GPU 1, and Rank 1 should correspond to GPU 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell any command which GPUs should be visible to them by setting the variable `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`. E.g.

```sh
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=2,3 python run.py <args>
```

This will only make GPU 2 and 3 visible to that process and thus DDP will only run on those GPUs that you specified. (Note that this is zero-indexed, i.e. `0` is the first GPU.)

Comment: Can I say CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=cpu,0,0?  I want a fully customizable mapping. I have reasons.